# event bus vuejs not emit event to pass data to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using for the first time the Vue event bus to pass data to child components from the main vue instance. After some testing I'm not able to get the data inside my components, I think the code is correct, but I'm not sure of this. Is something wrong in the code? 
I have three separate file (I'm not using webpack). Two js files that will hold the main vue instance and the components and a file that will hold the template. I'm developing a wordpress theme.
Any help?

```
// app.js file
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue(); // Global event bus

Vue.directive('prlx', VuePrlx.VuePrlxDirective);

new Vue({
  el: '#ume',
  router,
  data: {
    pageData: [],
    feedImg: []
  },
  watch: {
    $route( to, from ){
      console.log('main instance:'+ to, from);
      this.getPage();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPage: function(){
      //console.log(this.$route);
      var slug = this.$route.fullPath.replace(/\//g, "")
      axios.get(uptheme.pages_rest_url+'?slug='+ slug)
        .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        response.data.forEach( (item, i) => {
          this.pageData = [item];
          if( item.embedded.gallery_images ){
            item.embedded.gallery_images.forEach( (img) => {
              this.feedImg.push(img);
            });
          }
        });
      });
      this.$eventHub.$emit('page_data', this.pageData);
    },
  }
});
```

components.js file:

```
Vue.component('ume-about',{
  template: '#about-tpl',
  data() {
    return {
      pageData: [],
      feedImg: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$eventHub.$on('page_data', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.pageData.push(data);
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    $eventHub.$off('page_data');
  }
});
```

about-template.php file

```
// This file will only hold the template
<script type="text/x-template" id="about-tpl">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
<!-- page cover -->
    <div class="row m-0" v-for="page in pageData">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-pagecover p-0" v-if="page.embedded.first_featured_image">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100 position-absolute" :src="page.embedded.first_featured_image">
        <h1 class="text-white position-relative mt-5 pl-5 pt-5" style="z-index:2;" >{{ page.title.rendered }}</h1>
        <h4 class="text-white position-relative pl-5" style="z-index:2;" v-if="page.ucm._page_subtitle[0]">{{ page.ucm._page_subtitle[0] }}</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="overlay position-absolute"></div>
    </div>
<!-- main content -->
    <div class="row m-0" v-for="page in pageData">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-md-5 mb-md-5 p-5">
        <p class="" v-html="page.content.rendered"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-md-5 mb-md-5 p-0">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" :src="page.embedded.second_featured_image">  
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- parallax -->
    <uptheme-parallax v-for="(page, idx) in pageData" :url="page.embedded.parallax_image" :message="page.excerpt.rendered" ></uptheme-parallax>
<!-- swiper slider -->
    <uptheme-swiper :feed-img="feedImg"></uptheme-swiper>
<!-- colonna 1 -->
    <div class="row m-0" v-for="page in pageData">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-0 mt-md-5 mb-md-5" v-if="page.embedded.col_1_image">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" :src="page.embedded.col_1_image" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-5 mt-md-5 mb-md-5" v-if="page.ucm._col_1[0]">
        <h4 class="" v-if="page.ucm._col_1_title[0]">{{ page.ucm._col_1_title[0] }}</h4>
        <p class="" v-html="page.ucm._col_1[0]"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- colonna 2 -->
    <div class="row m-0" v-for="page in pageData">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-5 mt-md-5 mb-md-5" v-if="page.ucm._col_2[0]">
        <h4 class="" v-if="page.ucm._col_2_title[0]">{{ page.ucm._col_2_title[0] }}</h4>
        <p class="" v-html="page.ucm._col_2[0]"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-md-5 mb-md-5 p-0" v-if="page.embedded.col_2_image">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" :src="page.embedded.col_2_image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end container-fluid -->
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, there is no error. The console will not log nothing, I'm logging the data only for the component now to see if data are passed, but nothing showed!

Comment: I've added an answer which was too long for a comment which could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$eventHub.$emit('page_data', this.pageData);` is not in your axios function and so will return nothing

```
axios.get(uptheme.pages_rest_url+'?slug='+ slug)
    .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        response.data.forEach( (item, i) => {
          this.pageData = [item];
          if( item.embedded.gallery_images ){
            item.embedded.gallery_images.forEach( (img) => {
              this.feedImg.push(img);
            });
          }
        });

        this.$eventHub.$emit('page_data', this.pageData);
    });
```

Comment: I'm inspecting the vue debug console in chrome and the event is emitted. Do I need to move the event inside the `.then()` callback of axios?

Comment: @guggio yes, the event is being trigger immediately after the axios call is made so it's not waiting for the response and just returns nothing (I've moved the emit into the `.then()` in my answer

Comment: I will test and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've solved. Now to retrive the data inside the data I need only to add the event payload into the `pageData` array right? Nothing to change inside the component?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Right now it looks like you are overwriting the pageData with `[item]` each time in your `response.data.forEach` function. What you may need to do is for that is `this.pageData.push(item)`

Comment: The data are passed correctly into the payload, `.push()` will give me problems sometime. What I need to do now is get the data in the component and pass them to the `pageData` that is defined inside it

Comment: In the about-template.php file? That will need to be a vue component and you use the same code that you have for components.js just have the about-template.php as the template. What I normally like to do to keep things tidy is create a single file component [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and then to call that file I use, using yours as an example, `Vue.component('ume-about', require('./components/umeAbout.vue').default)`. I hope that makes sense and answers your query

Comment: I'm not using webpack at the moment but all seems to working fine. Thanks for the help